# If is True from the beginning in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a ping pong game and want to reset the ball when it hit edges of the game. code for right edge works fine but when i add left edge's code it freezes the ball.in fact it resets over and over.because the if is true from the start(idk how)

this is the part of the code that works fine.when hits the left bounces when hits the right edge resets

```
function moveBall() {
// reference useful variables
var playgroundHeight = parseInt($("#playground").height());
var playgroundWidth = parseInt($("#playground").width());
var ball = pingpong.ball;
// check playground boundary
// check bottom edge
if (ball.y + ball.speed*ball.directionY > playgroundHeight)
{
ball.directionY = -1;
}
// check top edge
if (ball.y + ball.speed*ball.directionY < 0)
{
ball.directionY = 1;
}
// check right edge
if (ball.x +ball.speed*ball.directionX > playgroundWidth)
{
// player B lost.


// reset the ball;
ball.x = 250;
ball.y = 100;
$("#ball").css({
"left": ball.x,
"top" : ball.y
});
ball.directionX = -1;
}
// check left edge


if (ball.x + ball.speed*ball.directionX < 0)
{
ball.directionX = 1;
}
ball.x += ball.speed * ball.directionX;
ball.y += ball.speed * ball.directionY;
```

but when i add this lines for left edge

```
// check left edge
if (ball.x + ball.speed*ball.directionX < 0)
{
// player A lost.
// reset the ball;
ball.x = 150;
ball.y = 100;
$("#ball").css({
"left": ball.x,
"top" : ball.y
});
ball.directionX = 1;
}
```

ball doesn't move anymore.like it's resetting again and again.

---

Comment: if complete code is needed please comment

Comment: I am sure we will get this running - could you please open a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: i created s jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ghavidel/ha65cous/6/ but don't know how to connect js to html.it's my first time

Comment: I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/21eq2ujn/1/ and it actually looks fine - execpt I had to reorganize the first part of your javascript a little to get it working